# What is a difference between channel ID and channel name in notifications

Tags: android

I tried find what is difference between channel ID and channel name in notifications.

Why `NotificationChannel` requires two options,  why not one option for example just channel id?

Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From DOCS

[**`setChannelId()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setChannelId(java.lang.String))

- Specifies the channel the notification should be delivered on.

[**`Channel Name`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#NotificationChannel(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int))

- **The user visible name of the channel**. You can rename this channel when the system locale changes by listening for the `Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED` broadcast. The recommended maximum length is 40 characters; the value may be truncated if it is too long

Comment: But when I sent notification to modern devices I can't see where is channel name

Comment: @user10797717 You can find channel here Go to setting->You app -> notification info